# Why do my access points get disconnected randomly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have a main wireless router which is provided by my broadband company. It had no problem but as the wireless could not cover the whole house I added two new routers which are connected by cable to the first one.
My DHCP starts from 192.168.0.4. So .1 is the main router and .2, .3 are the other routers.  DHCP on additional routers are disabled.

But the problem is, my devices get disconnected often. Like once per hour.  I do not know why are the like this but is there any special configuration that I need to do?

The problem is not about wireless, even devices that are connected by wire get disconnected too.

Any idea?

Comment: Which devices get disconnected from what? From each other? From the Internet? Devices connected to the main router? All devices?

Comment: Double check that the wireless routers are broadcasting on different channels...

Comment: Here's an article I found that may help you: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ConfiguringTwoWirelessRoutersWithOneSSIDNetworkNameAtHomeForFreeRoaming.aspx

Comment: @DavidSchwartz They get disconnected from internet.  And I released that each router get disconnected in a different time. For example once router no. 3 disconnects and sometime later no. 2 stops working. So it's not like they all stop at the same time.

Comment: @BenPlont yes I did. They are all in different channels.  1, 6 and 11 i think.